# NumPy C-API: convert type object to type number

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-c-api

The function

```
PyObject* PyArray_TypeObjectFromType(int);
```

converts the type number for a NumPy scalar type (NPY_BOOL, NPY_BYTE, ...) to the corresponding type object.

How do you do the opposite conversion, from the type object for a NumPy scalar type to the corresponding type number?

**Edit:** The following code is based on kwatford's answer. It accepts both type objects such as int and numpy.int16, and strings such as "int", u"int" and "int16".

```
int numpyScalarTypeNumber(PyObject* obj)
{
    PyArray_Descr* dtype;
    if(!PyArray_DescrConverter(obj, &dtype)) return NPY_NOTYPE;
    int typeNum = dtype->type_num;
    Py_DECREF(dtype);
    return typeNum;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can get `PyArray_Descr` structs rather than `PyArray_TypeObject`s, you can simply look at the [type_num](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#PyArray_Descr.type_num) field. The descr structs can be acquired via the type number using [PyArray_DescrFromType](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html?highlight=numpy%20pyarray_typeobjectfromtype#PyArray_DescrFromType). If you look at that link, there are also a few more functions for converting various things into descr structs. They're probably more useful in general than the type objects, and they contain references to their types as well.

Comment: That does not answer my question. I only have the type object to work with. I'm writing a Python extension module where one of the functions has a Python interface that takes a type object for a scalar type.

Comment: Then you're probably looking for [PyArray_DescrConverter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_DescrConverter) which should take a type or name of a type (or other things you can give to `numpy.dtype`) and get the descr for it. From that you can get the type number, type kind, type object, or whatever else you want.